# CSS select either <thead> or <tbody> from <table>

Tags: css, sass, styles, css-tables

I have the following problem. I have plenty of tables, but they all have different structure: one have `<table><thead><tbody>` type, while the others have `<table><tbody>` only.

And I need to apply css for thead (if it set in table) OR to tbody (it is set always). I shouldn't set styles for both of them, only for the first who goes after `<table>` tag.

So if I have

```
<table>
 <thead>...</thead>
   <tbody>...<tbody>
</table>
```

then CSS should be applied only for thead.

And vice versa if I have:

```
<table>
  <tbody>...</tbody>
<table>
```

then CSS should be applied for tbody.

*I wish there was something like 'if thead is set then...'*

Comment: Just add classes to the tbody & thead, then select them to apply css to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is an option, you could use a hack with [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) selector.

For example, you will select either one of them which is the first child of a `<table>`:

```css
table > thead:first-child, table > tbody:first-child{
  /* properties here */
}
```

In this case, if a `thead` is present, `tbody` will not be the first child. Otherwise, if there is no `thead`, `tbody` will be the first child.

See it in action:

```css
table > thead tr, /* Select the <tr> in a <thead> if present */
table > tbody:first-child tr:first-child /* Select the first <tr> in a <tbody> when the <thead> is not present */
{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}

table{
margin-top:1em;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>This is a table with header</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>This is the body</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>This is a table without header</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>This is the body</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank u so much! You've solved my problem! I was trying to do the hack with :first-child but it seems to me that I used the wrong syntax or smth of the kind.
Again, big thanks to you!

Comment: Just hope that no tables have a `<caption>` or any `<colgroup>` elements.